# Availability of 'Panchvinsh Brahman' online

Tags: scripture, resource

'Brahmans' are the one of the earliest category of Hindu scriptures. 'Satpatha Brahman' is the most famous among them. 'Panchvinsh Brahman' belongs this category. 'Vedic Index" vol.I&II.by Macdonell often quotes from this book. Some of the references  quoted from this book by Mcdonell are quite perturbing to me particularly about a king who murdered his priest because he insisted to worship Indra.

I want to verify this from the original text of 'Panchvinsh Brahman'. May anyone help me by suggesting it's availability online or a book form that can be purchased online or even the publisher where this book may be available.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the book  [**Pancavimsa Brahmana**](https://archive.org/details/pancavimsabrahma032052mbp)  by Caland. W.

> [image]

You can also **read** the book online through the reader provide by the site.

---

You can **purchase** this book on [**amazon.com**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001FB1L10)  or from Exotic India:

> [image]

---

Comment: @SwiftPuskar Thanks a lot for the help. I will certainly go through it.

Comment: The original publisher above is Baptist Mission Press. Their translations were only made to put Hinduism in a bad light and any translation with their endorsement is highly suspect.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda - Swamiji ,Thanks for clarification. Actually I wasn't aware about the intention of author. But given the answer as requested by OP. BTW your comment is very useful for the readers of the book.:)

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Thanks for forewarning. I am well aware of inefficacy English translation has of Hindu scripture in general set aside their intention , particularly in case of RigVeda translations. Do you have any idea where the orignal may be available ? Read I mentioned 'original' in the question.

Comment: you might try http://www.mlbd.com/